# Hanging Requests with SignalR?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

we have some server issues and try to eliminate all potential problems. I checked the Worker-Processes view in the IIS management tool and opened the view with opened the faulting worker process and saw a lof of signalR connect entries:

http://srv03.green-parrot.net/api2/Test.png

We use signalR only for a single page. The user starts a new search and we push the results with signalR to the user. Then we keep the connection open for another search. I found a similiar question here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3295, but they do not talk about EndRequest. I also checked the connection timeout and it is configured for 20.000ms, so after this time the client should automatically reconnect (or not responding anymore).

Question: Is this normal and if not, what can I do?

Btw: We are running on signalR 2.2 and the Client IP is the loadbalancer. I asked the same question here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3431, but I recognized that there are almost no answers for the last days.